# Activar y desactivar función de JQUERY con el mismo botón onclick

Tags: jquery, entrada

Tengo una función que ejecutar al hacerle click en un checkbox que en la otra lista de checkbox solo pueda seleccionar 3 input:checkbox. 
Quiero que al volver a desmarca la el primer checkbox pueda volver a marcar todos los input:checkbox otra vez.

Pongo el ejemplo del código aquí. Como dije quiero desmarcar el primer input:checkbox y que ya se no se ejecute la función que solo me permite seleccionar 3 abajo.

Gracias al que me ayude!

```js
function limite() {
var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="button" onclick="limite();" value="asd"/> Activar solo que seleccionen 3 casillas

       <div class="pricing-levels-3">
          <p><strong>Seleccionar</strong></p>
          <input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacerlo sería verificando el estado del `check` que controlará la cantidad de `checkbox` marcados. *(change)* , si este está marcado entonces removemos el `:checked` a todos los `checkbox` y asignamos un nuevo limite `3` , caso contrario asignamos a `limit` el total de `checkbox` con el nombre `single-checkbox`

```js
$(function() {
    var max = $('input.single-checkbox').length;
    var limit = max;
    $(document).on('change','#checkLimit',function(){
        if(this.checked) {
            $('input.single-checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
            limit = 3;
        }
        else limit = max;
    });
    $(document).on('change','input.single-checkbox', function(evt) {
       if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
           this.checked = false;
       }
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="button" id="checkLimit" value="asd"/> Activar solo que seleccionen 3 casillas
<div class="pricing-levels-3">
  <p><strong>Seleccionar</strong></p>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox"  name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
</div>
```